# Selenium (Java) and TestNG framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am working on building framework using selenium (java) with TestNG for Web a based application. Since I'm pretty new to all this , can any body suggest or provide any information how can I proceed or what things should I take care of?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would recommend http://www.toolsqa.com/ if you want some tips etc. 
For example Page Object Modul is quite good. It helps you reuse the elements and incases a element change you have to change 1 element instead fixing that element in all the tests.
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/. 
That site has alot of tips and examples which you can use.

Comment: It is good for basic understanding. But Im still not clear as how should manage test methods like making different suites and how make reporting effective.

Comment: Refer this :- 

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad. Please ask specific questions.

- As you have mentioned you are using `testng`. For making different suites use `testng.xml`, you may check `testng.org`, you will find relevant examples.
- For reporting, you can use `reportng` or some other reporting
  tools (`allure`) which will act as a plugin and generate nice reports
  based on the `testng-results.xml`.
- For modular selenium tests, you can use the tried and tested page
  object model.

Please read up on the above things.